# What is the latest version of iTunes that will run on a PowerPC-based Mac?

Tags: itunes, powerpc

What is the latest iTunes that will still run on a Power PC based Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version (iTunes 10) will run on a PowerPC machine but it has some small limitations (primarily it can not play High Definition video from the iTunes Store)

System Requirements:

> Mac computer with an Intel, PowerPC G5 or G4 processor
>   Intel, PowerPC G5 or 1.0GHz PowerPC G4 or faster processor is required to play Standard Definition video from the iTunes Store
>   2.0GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor is required to play HD video, an iTunes LP, or iTunes Extras from the iTunes Store
>   Mac OS X version 10.5 or later

[Source](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) (iTunes Download Page)

Answer (score 4):

as long as [iTunes 10](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) (newer version of iTunes) need OS X 10.5 (Leopard) as it's [minimum requirement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes#System_requirements) and you can install leopard on your Powerpc then latest itunes that was supported by Powerpc is the last one [iTunes 10](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).

Comment: It's quite possible to make an app that requires 10.5 and have it be Intel only. In this case it isn't so. In say, Chrome's case it is so.